# python combine values for a specific key separated by comma

Tags: python, json, jq

Is there a way to combine multiple values for a specific key separated by comma. In my case i am trying to print multiple `service.names` values so they can be printed in a single line separated by comma.

How can i combine the `service.name` values separated by comma so they print like below:

```
{
  "number": 1,
  "service name": "FTP-Server, SSH-Server"
}
```

I tried below in pyjq but it separates values by a complete separate block.

```
.group[].group[] | { "number": .number, "service name": .service[].name }
```

Here is the output i am getting

```
{
  "number": 1,
  "service name": "FTP-Server"
}
{
  "number": 1,
  "service name": "SSH-Server"
}
```

Given below same data with/without object-dictionary. I am ok with any format.

JSON file with object-dictionary enabled

```
{
    "objects-dictionary": [
        {
            "name": "FTP-Server", 
            "port": "21", 
            "type": "service-tcp", 
            "uid": "ef245528-9a3d-11d6-9eaa-3e5a6fdd6a6a"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "SSH-Server", 
            "port": "22", 
            "type": "service-tcp", 
            "uid": "dff4f7ba-9a3d-11d6-91c1-3e5a6fdd5151"
        }
    ], 
    "base": [
        {
           "number": 1, 
            "service": [
                "ef245528-9a3d-11d6-9eaa-3e5a6fdd6a6a",
                "dff4f7ba-9a3d-11d6-91c1-3e5a6fdd5151"
            ],
            "uid": "90088436-ac42-4363-84a6-3dbebf3c11f0"
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON file without object-dictionary

```
{
    "group": [
        {
            "group": [
                { 
                    "number": 1, 
                    "service": [
                        {
                            "name": "FTP-Server", 
                            "port": "21", 
                            "type": "service-tcp", 
                            "uid": "ef245528-9a3d-11d6-9eaa-3e5a6fdd6a6a"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name": "SSH-Server", 
                            "port": "22", 
                            "type": "service-tcp", 
                            "uid": "dff4f7ba-9a3d-11d6-91c1-3e5a6fdd5151"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "uid": "90088436-ac42-4363-84a6-3dbebf3c11f0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You only want to export all the values of a single field in a list as a comma-separated list?

Comment: yes but only key values corresponding to the group. Say the group has one number, one uid and two service. i want the service to print in a single line. so if there are many groups exists, the script can print them separately

Comment: @peak, acceptable output is updated on the top of the question already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather unclear what you expect as output, but given your last example and using `jq` you can concatenate both service names together:

```
<file jq '[.group[].group[].service[].name] | join(",")'
```

Note that `join` expects an array, so the `name`s need to be inside an array `[ ... ]`.

If you need to add this string within the object itself, you might do something like:

```
<file jq '.service.name=([.group[].group[].service[].name] | join(","))'
```

Comment: Absolutely correct @oliv. I have just altered to fit it in my script as `.group[].group[] | { "service": ([.service[].name] | join(","))}`. This works as expected. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

With your second JSON text, the following filter:

```
.group[].group[]
| { "number": .number, "service name": ([.service[].name]|join(", ")) }
```

produces the output that you've indicated you expected (including the space after the comma):

```
{
  "number": 1,
  "service name": "FTP-Server, SSH-Server"
}
```

Comment: Yes absolutely that's what i did. Thank You @peak